# Sometimes loops threads is stuck without ending even if task of loop ends

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on my first threaded python project 
and I have a problem with threads sometimes it works but sometimes it stucks without ending why ??

**Example of my code**

```
import threading,signal,sys,queue,time

def write(text):
  sys.stdout.write(text + "\n")
  sys.stdout.flush()


class runThread(threading.Thread):

     def __init__(self):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.daemon = True

     def run(self):
         while not isKilled(): # used if user use ctrl_c to stop the task before finish
             if  numbers.empty(): # task has finished
                 break
             num = numbers.get()
             write("[*] Thread-{} : number: {}".format(self.ident,num))
             time.sleep(1)

def mainThread():
   for _ in range(5):
      thread = runThread()
      thread.start()
      THREADS.append(thread)
   for t in THREADS: t.join()



def start():
  global event
  global kill
  global isKilled
  global handler
  global THREADS
  global numbers 

  event = threading.Event()
  kill = lambda : event.set()
  isKilled = lambda : event.isSet()
  handler = lambda sig,fream: kill()

  THREADS = []
  numbers = queue.Queue()

  for n in range(1000):
      numbers.put(n)

  runMainThread = threading.Thread(target=mainThread)
  runMainThread.daemon = True
  runMainThread.start()
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,handler)

  while runMainThread.isAlive():
      continue
  print("[*] Done")
  runMainThread.join()
if __name__=="__main__":
    start()
```

Sometimes it works like a charm but sometimes it stucks after last print of number
and didn't go to `print('[*] Done')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple threads execute the following code:

```
if numbers.empty(): # task has finished
   break 
num = numbers.get()
```

Imagine this: assume `numbers` only has one number left. thread1 executes `numbers.empty()`, it returns `False`. Then the before thread1 executes `numbers.get()`, thread2 is scheduled to run. thread2 executes `numbers.empty()`, it also returns `False` since the last element has not been taken. thread2 executes `numbers.get()` and take the last element. Then thread1 will block on `numbers.get()` forever.

According to the documents [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.empty):

> Queue.empty()
>   Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. If empty() returns True it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to put() will not block. Similarly, if empty() returns False it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to get() will not block.

Solutions would be:

1. Set timeout for `numbers.get()`:

   ```
   try:
       num = numbers.get(timeout=5) # wait 5 seconds at most.
   except queue.Empty:
       break
   ```
2. Use `threading.Lock` to ensure threads won't interrupt each other when they are between `numbers.empty()` and `numbers.get()`.

   ```
   # in start()
   global lock
   lock = threading.Lock()

   # in runThread.run()
   lock.acquire()
   if numbers.empty():
       lock.release()
       break
   num = numbers.get()
   lock.release()
   write("[*] Thread-{} : number: {}".format(self.ident,num))
   ```